# Exit Nterm and term quick

Tags: neovim, init.lua

Is there a proper way to exit nterm ?

My current solution is to enter from nterm to the terminal with `i` and then `c-d`.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? Otherwise may be could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-) and let others know that the answer is worth reading ;-)

Comment: Yes, of curse. I just wasn't sure because of the ``<c-s-q>`` Mapping... 
Thx, for the help :D

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in Normal mode you can do `:q` or simply `ZZ` as for a normal window.

If you are in Terminal mode you can switch to Normal mode with <kbd>Ctrl \</kbd><kbd>Ctrl n</kbd> and then `:q` or `ZZ`

To simplify that you can add a Terminal mapping to <kbd>Ctrl q</kbd>:

```
tnoremap <C-q> <C-\><C-n>
```

Or in Lua:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("t", "<C-q>", "<C-\\><C-n>", {noremap = true})
```

You can combine both in one:

```
tnoremap <C-S-q> <C-\><C-n>ZZ
```

Or in Lua:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("t", "<C-S-q>", "<C-\\><C-n>ZZ", {noremap = true})
```

Vim/Neovim quit when the last window is closed.

A solution is then to:

- Switch back to the terminal window
- Close the terminal buffer

```
tnoremap <C-q> <C-\><C-n>:bd!<CR>
```

Or in Lua:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("t", "<C-q>", "<C-\\><C-n>:bd!<CR>", {noremap = true})
```

Comment: Thx, for the shortcuts :D 
I had a problem with <C-\> should i escape it ?
I really would like to go from nterm/:term to normal mode without closing vim... 
And it seems that they are all closing vim...

Comment: When you are closing the last window Vim close. To avoid that you have to create another window before closing the one with the terminal. The new <C-S-q> mapping in terminal mode does that (leave Terminal mode, create a new window, close the terminal window)

Comment: Okay, thx :D I got it working with <C-\\><C-n>.
But I'm curious is there no way to go from nterm to normal ?

Comment: You need to escape the ``\`` if you write your mapping in Lua. I believe the answer to your question the `terminal` buffer is not a normal editing buffer. You can't switch it to a "normal" buffer.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your terminal answer. I browsed the web but couldn't find any answers to this topic. By the way, I tested your commands. 1 and 2 works fine, but I struggle with the 3rd... I realized something wired when closing the buffers...
The command ":q" behaves always different when files are empty or not...
When I close the first buffer or 2nd or soo.. It doesn't feels right to me, or it is not described anywhere how it behaves in certain scenarios...

Comment: I noticed that `<C-S-q>` has a special effect on the Linux terminal. I believe that without the `S` it is working fine. At least to me ;-)

Comment: Yes this is true. I just meant the command.... not the keymapping.
But i guess it would work with custom settings in the terminal...

Comment: Thats what i ment with :q
When i open nvim with no filename , write some text, make a new buffer which is empty, then i write :q, it will close new generated Buffer. Now I'm Back where i started "1st" buffer. Now when generate a new buffer, write text, save file with filename and now i press :q it will NOT close current Buffer and go to "1st" Buffer. When i now save this buffer with filename then press :q it will quit all Buffers... But if you open nvim go straigth to a terminal session make new Buffer
then press :q it quits all.
These are all different behaviours.
That's what confused me.

Comment: Thanks for the very precise explanation. It is much more now. When you execute `:q` Vim close the current window. If it was the last window Vim tries to quit. But if there is some unsaved buffer it doesn't and switch to the first of these buffers.

Comment: I have found a simpler way to get closer to the `<C-d><space>` experience. I have updated the solution accordingly :-) Let me know if it solves your problem ;-)